# Punjabi Unicode font in webview

Tags: android, webview, font-face

I have created a wordpress website by using Raavi font. That i have upload the font by using Wordpress Font Uploader. same website I am running in WebView. When I run my android project in emulator it shows me the font.. but when I run my phone.. if do not show the font... 
How can add my Raavi.ttf font in WebView and android project.. So that when I run the application WebView use font from my application not from webserver....
my code is given below

```
package com.aarcreationz.bhajanmala;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    WebView mWeb;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWeb = new WebView(this);
        mWeb.setClickable(true);
        mWeb.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setContentView(mWeb);
        WebSettings settings = mWeb.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                mProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                mProgress.setTitle("Please Wait!");
                mProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgress.show();

            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                    mProgress.hide();
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        mWeb.loadUrl("http://www.aarcreationz.com/mala");
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWeb.canGoBack())
        {
            mWeb.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```